# Hover transform scale issue on Chrome

Tags: html, css

I showed my problem on [this film](http://youtu.be/UQ7gwPmbRz8) and the browser is Chrome (v. 44.0.2403.107 m). The background image should scale up and down after mouse hover and left. But sometimes Chrome skips animation giving this rough movements. I tested it also on IE, Mozilla, Opera and there is no such issue, everything is fine.

I'm working on category element zoom on hover, but I want only the image to scale and not description. Previously I could achieve it with `background-size` `transition` on `.categoryItem` list element, but unfortunately IE does not support percentages in `bacground-size` for `transition`s. So I came up with below workaround, which is less, but still problematic.

Why I'm adding style to an element in HTML - it's the part of jquery script. The concept is to allow user add their own images in CMS through `img` tag, which is the part of `li` element, but it's hidden, and it's `src` is copied to `div`'s background-image url.

I tried:

- Adding `z-index`es to `categoryItem` and `categoryItemImage`
- Adding `webkit-backface-visibility:hidden`
- Adding `ease-in-out`
- Delaying `transition`
- Searching similar problem on google for couple hours

What else I can do?

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.categoryItem {
  position: relative;
  background: black;
  transition: all 2.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 2.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 2.5s;
  -ms-transition: all 2.5s;
}
.categoryItemImage {
  position: relative;
  transition: all 1.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 1.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 1.5s;
  -ms-transition: all 1.5s;
}
.categoryItem:hover .categoryItemImage {
  transform: scale(1.035, 1.035);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.035, 1.035);
  -moz-transform: scale(1.035, 1.035);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.035, 1.035);
  transition: all 2.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 2.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 2.5s;
  -ms-transition: all 2.5s;
}
.categoryItemDescription {
  max-width: 500px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50px;
  bottom: 100px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<ul class="categoriesOverview">
  <li class="categoryItem" style="height: 433.3px; overflow:hidden;">
    <div class="categoryItemImage" style="height:inherit; background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/1920/572) !important; background-position: 50% 50%;"></div>
    <div class="categoryItemDescription">
      <h2>The title</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque sed ex sed neque dignissim imperdiet eget a odio. Etiam semper mollis scelerisque. Integer rutrum, dolor ac efficitur viverra, nulla augue vulputate turpis, a vulputate sapien leo
        a dui. Sed id lectus tellus. Curabitur at congue ante.</p>
      <a class="button" href="#">Click me</a>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Looks like a bug in the latest Chrome release. I don't think that there is anything in your code that can be causing this issue

Answer (score 0):

It certainly looks like a bug, but setting the values manually seems to resolve it, or at least make it happen less often. Like this:

```js
var imgElem = document.querySelector('.categoryItemImage');
var elem = document.querySelector('.categoryItem');


imgElem.onmouseover = function(e){
    console.log(window.getComputedStyle(imgElem).getPropertyValue('transform'))
    imgElem.style['transform'] = 'matrix(1.035,0,0,1.035,0,0)'
    imgElem.style['-webkit-transform'] = 'matrix(1.035,0,0,1.035,0,0)'
}
imgElem.onmouseout = function(e){
    console.log(window.getComputedStyle(imgElem).getPropertyValue('transform'))
    imgElem.style['transform'] = 'matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)'
    imgElem.style['-webkit-transform'] = 'matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)'
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.categoryItem {
  position: relative;
  background: black;
  transition: all 2.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 2.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 2.5s;
  -ms-transition: all 2.5s;
}
.categoryItemImage {
  position: relative;
  transition: all 1.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 1.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 1.5s;
  -ms-transition: all 1.5s;
}
.categoryItem:hover .categoryItemImage {
 
  -moz-transform: scale(1.035, 1.035);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.035, 1.035);
  transition: all 2.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 2.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 2.5s;
  -ms-transition: all 2.5s;
}
.categoryItemDescription {
  max-width: 500px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50px;
  bottom: 100px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<ul class="categoriesOverview">
  <li class="categoryItem" style="height: 433.3px; overflow:hidden;">
    <div class="categoryItemImage" style="height:inherit; background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/1920/572) !important; background-position: 50% 50%;"></div>
    <div class="categoryItemDescription">
      <h2>The title</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque sed ex sed neque dignissim imperdiet eget a odio. Etiam semper mollis scelerisque. Integer rutrum, dolor ac efficitur viverra, nulla augue vulputate turpis, a vulputate sapien leo
        a dui. Sed id lectus tellus. Curabitur at congue ante.</p>
      <a class="button" href="#">Click me</a>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```